# Is decanting wine in a blender the same as in a decanter?

Tags: nutrition, physics

Is it true that putting wine in a blender for a few seconds (or using something like the Vinturi wine aerator) gives me the same result as putting the wine in a decanter for 1 or 2 hours as suggested here: http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2011/12/18/hyperdecanting-wine/ ?

Comment: Seems to come down to the reaction with air, which should indeed be higher by using a blender, so it sounds reasonable. The funny thing is that you actually stir homebrewed wine in order to get gas (like CO2) *out* of the wine after the fermentation. Your question might also be answerable on http://homebrew.stackexchange.com, while they are actually more about the brewing process of course.